# Is it safe to charge a 6V battery with an automatic 12V charger?

Tags: battery-charging, charger

I have this automatic 12v-24v charger, that has several features.
Such as automatic-manual switch, floating charge, intelligent pulse repair type (it says).

I've charged my 12v battery pretty quick with this charger. But I do have a 6v battery and wondering if I could hook it up in the charger.

I'm aware that I could buy another 6v battery, connect it in series with the other one, however I'm also aware that they might not get equally charged. Like the other one could get damaged, and the other one get charged just fine.

[image]

Comment: You will most likely blow the battery.

Comment: Don't 6V is not 12V. Otherwise they would be equal...

Comment: If the charger was suitable for 6 V batteries the manufacturer would have been sure to include that in the marketing material so as to increase sales.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. Unless the product specifically says it’s able to charge a 6V battery, you will wind up damaging the battery. You’re also correct in thinking that it’s not a good idea to connect another 6V battery in series with your existing battery; EE StackExchange is rife with posts on that topic.